# Significant latency with touch/stylus tracking when using notetaking/sketch apps?

Tags: stylus, drawing, lagging

I am using a Adonit Jot Pro stylus for sketching and hand writing notes. On my Nexus 5X and even more so on my iPad Air (2013 or 2014), the responsiveness to the stylus is acceptable and/or great.

On my Android tablet (Project Tango Yellowstone dev kit, specs below) the lag is so significant that when trying to sign my name at normal speed in cursive, the last few characters look like a low amplitude sine wave. It's as if the stylus contact gets so far ahead that whatever interpolation code used to draw is sampling at a very low rate or the contact gets so far to the right of the current 'drawing position' that it just flattens out the letters.

Comparing the Nexus 5X with the tablet via Google Keep hand written notes, the phone is much more responsive. On the iPad Air, the responsiveness is excellent.

So what determines this latency and is there a way to address it?

Specs

Screen: 7.02" 1920x1200 HD IPS (323 dpi)

Processor: NVIDIA Tegra K1 with 192 CUDA cores

Mem: 4 GB RAM

Storage: 128 GB